# In Swagger UI, how to open the response in a new window?

Tags: swagger-ui

Is there any way that I could open in a new window the response when I press the "execute" button in Swagger UI?

I get an HTML page response, so I would like to open it and see the message in a new window, as a webpage.

Looking into the swagger-ui-bundle, there's a `newWindow` variable that I guess is for that, but looking into the documentation I see just nothing.